# Reformat non-serializable JSON-ish data into a format suitable for value extraction in Python

Tags: python, json, regex, serialization

With the following simple Python script:

```
import json
file = 'toy.json'
data = json.loads(file)
print(data['gas']) # example
```

My data generates the error `...is not JSON serializable`.

With this, slightly more sophisticated, Python script:

```
import json
import sys

#load the data into an element
data = open('transactions000000000029.json', 'r')

#dumps the json object into an element
json_str = json.dumps(data)

#load the json to a string
resp = json.loads(json_str)

#extract an element in the response
print(resp['gas'])
```

The same.

What I'd like to do is extract all the values of a particular index, so ideally I'd like to render the input like so:

```
...
"hash": "0xf2b5b8fb173e371cbb427625b0339f6023f8b4ec3701b7a5c691fa9cef9daf63",    
"gasUsed": "21000",
"hash": "0xf8f2a397b0f7bb1ff212b6bcc57e4a56ce3e27eb9f5839fef3e193c0252fab26"
"gasUsed": "21000"
...
```

The data looks like this:

```
{
  "blockNumber": "1941794",
  "blockHash": "0x41ee74e34cbf9ef4116febea958dbc260e2da3a6bf6f601bfaeb2cd9ab944a29",
  "hash": "0xf2b5b8fb173e371cbb427625b0339f6023f8b4ec3701b7a5c691fa9cef9daf63",
  "from": "0x3c0cbb196e3847d40cb4d77d7dd3b386222998d9",
  "to": "0x2ba24c66cbff0bda0e3053ea07325479b3ed1393",
  "gas": "121000",
  "gasUsed": "21000",
  "gasPrice": "20000000000",
  "input": "",
  "logs": [],
  "nonce": "14",
  "value": "0x24406420d09ce7440000",
  "timestamp": "2016-07-24 20:28:11 UTC"
}
{
  "blockNumber": "1941716",
  "blockHash": "0x75e1602cad967a781f4a2ea9e19c97405fe1acaa8b9ad333fb7288d98f7b49e3",
  "hash": "0xf8f2a397b0f7bb1ff212b6bcc57e4a56ce3e27eb9f5839fef3e193c0252fab26",
  "from": "0xa0480c6f402b036e33e46f993d9c7b93913e7461",
  "to": "0xb2ea1f1f997365d1036dd6f00c51b361e9a3f351",
  "gas": "121000",
  "gasUsed": "21000",
  "gasPrice": "20000000000",
  "input": "",
  "logs": [],
  "nonce": "1",
  "value": "0xde0b6b3a7640000",
  "timestamp": "2016-07-24 20:12:17 UTC"
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve that?

I've been thinking that perhaps the best way would be to reformat it as valid json?

Or maybe to just treat it like regex?

Answer (score 1):

Your json file is not valid. This data should be a list of dictionaries. You should then separate each dictionary with a comma, Like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "blockNumber":"1941794",
      "blockHash": "0x41ee74bf9ef411d9ab944a29",
      "hash":"0xf2ef9daf63",
      "from":"0x3c0cbb196e3847d40cb4d77d7dd3b386222998d9",
      "to":"0x2ba24c66cbff0bda0e3053ea07325479b3ed1393",
      "gas":"121000",
      "gasUsed":"21000",
      "gasPrice":"20000000000",
      "input":"",
      "logs":[  

      ],
      "nonce":"14",
      "value":"0x24406420d09ce7440000",
      "timestamp":"2016-07-24 20:28:11 UTC"
   },
   {  
      "blockNumber":"1941716",
      "blockHash":"0x75e1602ca8d98f7b49e3",
      "hash":"0xf8f2a397b0f7bb1ff212e193c0252fab26",
      "from":"0xa0480c6f402b036e33e46f993d9c7b93913e7461",
      "to":"0xb2ea1f1f997365d1036dd6f00c51b361e9a3f351",
      "gas":"121000",
      "gasUsed":"21000",
      "gasPrice":"20000000000",
      "input":"",
      "logs":[  

      ],
      "nonce":"1",
      "value":"0xde0b6b3a7640000",
      "timestamp":"2016-07-24 20:12:17 UTC"
   }
]
```

Then use this to open the file:

```
with open('toy.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

You can then render the desired output like:

```
for item in data:
    print item['hash']
    print item['gasUsed']
```

Answer (score 0):

If each block is valid JSON data you can parse them seperatly:

```
data = []
with open('transactions000000000029.json') as inpt:
    lines = []
    for line in inpt:
        if line.startswith('{'):  # block starts
            lines = [line]
        else:
            lines.append(line)    
        if line.startswith('}'):  # block ends
            data.append(json.loads(''.join(lines)))

for block in data:
    print("hash: {}".format(block['hash']))
    print("gasUsed: {}".format(block['gasUsed']))
```

Comment: the trouble is that each block is *not* valid json

Comment: In your example data they are. What does your actual data look like?

Comment: just the same as the example but longer

Comment: when I tried it I got this error `ValueError: Extra data: line 16 column 1`